# In React, how should I pass a starting elapsed time to a stopwatch component and start a running incrementer from that elapsed time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, state, react-props

I can get a static elapsed seconds to display based on the pulled start time but I can't get the elapsed seconds to then continue counting. I know I probably shouldn't be using the props to update a state in the child but even without that I couldn't get it to work and tried that as a workaround. Any help is appreciated.

Parent looks like this:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      elapsedSeconds: -1
    };
    this.changeElapsedSecondsParent = this.changeElapsedSecondsParent.bind(this);
  }
  changeElapsedSecondsParent(newElapsed) {
    this.setState({
      elapsedSeconds: newElapsed
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { elapsedSeconds } = this.state;

   return (
     <div>
      <Stopwatch 
         elapsedSeconds={elapsedSeconds} 
         changeElapsed={this.changeElapsedSecondsParent}
       />
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child stopwatch looks like this:

```
const formattedSeconds = (sec) =>
  ~~(sec / 60) +
    ':' +
  ('0' + sec % 60).slice(-2)


export class Stopwatch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      secondsElapsed: -1,
      laps: [],
      lastClearedIncrementer: null
    };
    this.incrementer = null;
    this.handleStartClick = this.handleStartClick.bind(this);
    this.handleStopClick = this.handleStopClick.bind(this);
    this.handleResetClick = this.handleResetClick.bind(this);
    this.handleLapClick = this.handleLapClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.state.secondsElapsed < 0) {
      const getElapsedTime = async () => {
        try{
          const response =  await fetch(`api url`);
          if(response.ok){
            let jsonResponse = await response.json();
            /* start getting seconds elapsed since start */
            let currentServerTime = new Date(jsonResponse[0].currentTimeStamp).getTime() /1000;
            let currentD = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);
            let deltaDate = (currentServerTime-currentD);
            let raceStartTime = new Date(jsonResponse[0].startTime).getTime()/1000 - deltaDate;
            let secondsElapsedSinceStart = currentD - raceStartTime;
            /* end getting seconds elapsed since start */
            this.props.changeElapsed(secondsElapsedSinceStart);
          }
        }
        catch(error){
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
      getElapsedTime();
      let newElapsed = this.props.elapsedSeconds;
      this.incrementer = setInterval( () =>
      this.setState({
      secondsElapsed: newElapsed + 1
      })
      , 1000);
    } else {
      this.incrementer = setInterval( () =>
      this.setState({
      secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1
      })
      , 1000);
    }
  }

  handleStartClick() {
    /* start post request */
    const pushTime = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('apiurl', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({"startTime": "'2018-08-26 16:57:09'"})
        })
        if(response.ok){
          const jsonResponse = await response.json();
          return jsonResponse;
        }
        throw new Error('Request failed!');
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    pushTime();
  }

  handleStopClick() {
    clearInterval(this.incrementer);
    this.setState({
      lastClearedIncrementer: this.incrementer
    });
  }

  handleResetClick() {
    clearInterval(this.incrementer);
    this.setState({
      secondsElapsed: 0,
      laps: []
    });
  }

  handleLapClick() {
    this.setState({
      laps: this.state.laps.concat([this.props.elapsedSeconds])
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="stopwatch">
        <h1 className="stopwatch-timer">{formattedSeconds(this.state.secondsElapsed)}</h1>

        {(this.props.elapsedSeconds === 0 ||
          this.incrementer === this.state.lastClearedIncrementer
          ? <Button className="start-btn" onClick={this.handleStartClick.bind(this)}>start</Button>
          : <Button className="stop-btn" onClick={this.handleStopClick.bind(this)}>stop</Button>
        )}

        {(this.props.elapsedSeconds !== 0 &&
          this.incrementer !== this.state.lastClearedIncrementer
          ? <Button onClick={this.handleLapClick.bind(this)}>lap</Button>
          : null
        )}


        {(this.props.elapsedSeconds !== 0 &&
          this.incrementer === this.state.lastClearedIncrementer
          ? <Button onClick={this.handleResetClick.bind(this)}>reset</Button>
          : null
        )}

        <ul className="stopwatch-laps">
          { this.state.laps.map((lap, i) =>
              <li className="stopwatch-lap"><strong>{i + 1}</strong>/ {formattedSeconds(lap)}</li>)
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Button = (props) =>
  <button type="button" {...props} className={"btn " + props.className } />;
```

Comment: If it helps, this is the base stopwatch I modified https://codepen.io/seoh/pen/PPZYQy

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to define a constant in the constructor like:

```
this.deltaTime = null;
```

Then I created a changeDeltaTime function:

```
changeDeltaTime(newTime) {
    this.deltaTime = newTime
}
```

lastly, I updated that deltaTime inside the promiseand after the response within the componentDidUpdate() lifecycle method.

```
await this.changeDeltaTime(deltaDate);
```

In render, I waited the promise to be resolved through a prop passed by parent

```
return !this.props.finishedGet ? <span>Waiting on fetch...</span> : (this.renderStopwatch(this.state.time))
```

This also involves the renderStopwatch function to be created but it basically just houses what should be created once the promise resolves.